# Generate error if float or box splits page?

Tags: environments, luatex, page-breaking

Floats, parboxes, minipages, and some other environments cannot be split across a page. Fine. Not a problem, in my application. I can re-write things easily.

However, it seems that LaTeX will do something or other to solve the layout problem, without throwing an error. Maybe it will let excess content run off the page bottom. Maybe it will move content to a new page.

I do not want LaTeX to solve the problem. If I use an environment, but during typesetting it cannot fit entirely on one page, then I would like the compiler to halt right there, with an error message. Preferably my own message. Is this possible?

I realize that I can let typesetting complete, then review the PDF. But in a few cases the problem might be very subtle, and visually overlooked.

Using LuaLaTex with TeXlive 2016. Cannot use XeTeX.

EDIT: As David Carlisle noted below, my question is rather broad. Indeed, floats are the underlying cause: Every problem situation has a float hiding further down in its code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is rather broad and has no examples..

in classic Tex overfull vboxes are a warning not an error, that behaviour is built in to tex-the-program and isn't really changeable. (perhaps you could do a test on badness in the output routine, perhaps but in luatex I would do as I suggest at the end)

the one place that LaTeX "adjusts" things in the way you describe is if a float contains too much material, so you could make that an error by

```
\makeatletter
\def \@largefloatcheck{%
  \ifdim \ht\@currbox>\textheight
    \@tempdima -\textheight
    \advance \@tempdima \ht\@currbox
    %%%\@latex@warning {Float too large for page by \the\@tempdima}%
    \@latex@error{Float too large for page by \the\@tempdima}\@ehc
    \ht\@currbox \textheight
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

In lualatex however you have access to the Lua callback `vpack_quality` so you can make that throw a Lua error if its first argument is `"overfull"`

---

Compare this with pdftex and luatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\flushbottom

\ifx\directlua\undefined\else
\directlua{
function die_on_overfull(i,d,h,f,l)
if(i=="overfull") then
tex.error("overfull box",{"don't blame me, you asked for it"})
end
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback(
"vpack_quality",
die_on_overfull,
"make overfull vbox an error")
}\fi
\begin{document}

\section{one}
\rule{3cm}{20cm}

\section{two}
\rule{13cm}{4cm}
\rule{3cm}{10cm}

\section{three}
\rule{3cm}{4cm}

\rule{3cm}{4cm}



\end{document}
```

with pdftex

```
Overfull \vbox (39.95787pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
```

with luatex

```
! overfull box.
\@makecol ...putbox \vskip -\dimen@ \@textbottom }
                                                  \fi \global \maxdepth \@ma...

l.21 \section
           {two}
? h
don't blame me, you asked for it
? 
[2]
Overfull \hbox (24.88582pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 22--24
```

Comment: Your code is excellent. Below, I modified it by wrapping it an a `\gdef' so that the error could be switched on or off, depending on need.

Answer (score 0):

After testing David Carlisle's answer, which works, I was able to wrap it in a new environment. This allows me to turn the error on and off, so that it only appears when needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\flushbottom

\gdef\wraptest{ % enclosed code thanks to David Carlisle
  \ifx\directlua\undefined\else
  \directlua{
  function die_on_overfull(i,d,h,f,l)
  if(i=="overfull") then
  tex.error("\noexpand\n\noexpand\n ERROR: wrapmyfloat overfull.\noexpand\n\noexpand\n",{"Page \thepage\space has `wrapmyfloat' environment that overflows the allowed area.\noexpand\n"})
  end
  end
  luatexbase.add_to_callback(
  "vpack_quality",
  die_on_overfull,
  "make overfull vbox an error")
  }\fi
} % end gdef

\newenvironment{wrapmyfloat}
{\let\myresponse\wraptest%
\myresponse}
{\let\myresponse\relax}

\begin{document}

Test of wrapmyfloat, on following pages.\par

\section{one}
\rule{3cm}{20cm} % Is overfull, but no error, since not wrapped.

\section{two}
\begin{wrapmyfloat}
\rule{13cm}{4cm}
\rule{3cm}{10cm} % Change 10 to 20 to see overfull error.
\end{wrapmyfloat}

\section{three}
\rule{3cm}{4cm}

\rule{3cm}{4cm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: no the lua side doesn't respect groups in that way.  You should have a `\directlua` in the preamble that just defines the function `die_on_overfull` then your environment code should have a start code taht uses `_add_to_callback_` as above to register the calback and the end code shoudl have a `\directlua` calling `remove_from-callback` to unregister it. Separately your `\gdef` is at the top level so could just be `\newcommand`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: OK, I'll play with that. Thanks to this web site, I can look up specific code problems if I know how to phrase the question.